# UVM TB components to be used

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

[image]

I have a verification tb structure for a parity encoder decoder like shown below where I am driving data in to the Encoder, getting the output, adding randomised error to it and passing it as input to the Decoder.

My question is do I need two drivers to drive 1)Data_in_08p and 2) Data_corrupted_in? I should have a component that creates random error at random positions and xor's it with the Data_out_08p.  What should be the nature of thsi component i.e should it be a driver? Can I have two drivers in 1 agent or do I need to create two agents here?

To be precise, how we define our driver/env when one input of DUT depends upon a DUT output? How many sequences and sequencers and monitors will be there?

Comment: Can't you verify both encoder & decoder separately? Why are you making common testbench to verify 2 different blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The block diagram for the UVM testbench that would be required in order to verify the DUT would probably be something like this:

[image]

In UVM terms, you would require the following agents:

1. One active agent to send transactions to the input of the encoder block.
2. One passive agent to capture transactions at the output of the encoder block.
3. One reactive agent to send transactions to the input of the decoder block.
4. One passive agent to capture transactions at the output of the decoder block.

Please notice that the monitor sitting on the encoder output agent will capture the transactions and send them through an analysis port to the sequencer that is sitting on the decoder input agent.  This is called a "reactive" agent because it waits until something has been received in order to generate a transaction.  You will then inject errors from the sequence that is running on the decoder input agent's sequencer.

Verilab has a very good paper that talks in details about "Reactive Agents":
http://www.verilab.com/files/mastering_reactive_slaves.pdf

Comment: Can I also use driver callback here in my Decoder input agent instead?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about what you mean by driver callback.

Comment: Till now what I am doing is passing DUT signals from passive monitor to re-active sequencer and then generating error packets in sequence item. Instead, I want to have a callback driver which will generate the errors, and drive them to the DUT. Can I do it. Also if this is possible, can I have a switch in my uvm_config_db which I can configure to do any one of the two methods?

Comment: Got it.  I don't see a reason why it wouldn't be possible to do what you have described.

Comment: Thanks. But I am unsure of how the switch would control which method to use. eg. something like ....  if(agent2_config.switch == 1) use re_active_sqr1 on driver2 .... else use re_active_sqr2. Here, sqr1 would use error_seq_item and sqr2 would use normal seq_item and let the driver add errors. Both the sqr would be controlled by a virtual sequencer.